# Images in UICollectionView tap to full screen

Tags: uiimage, uicollectionview

I have an app on the go which requires two separate galleries of images. I've done this first one using a UICollectionView. I have everything set up so that the UICollectionView works perfectly, I just want to be able to click on each image to view them in a full screen. I would also like to know how to build a second UICollectionView on a different page with different images. Is it as easy as making a second UICollectionView and naming it myCollectionView2 and the same with the Image Arrays?

This is the code I currently have for the first collection:

```
#import "CollectionViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface CollectionViewController ()
{
    NSArray *ArrayOfImages;
}

@end

@implementation CollectionViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self myCollectionView1]setDataSource:self];
    [[self myCollectionView1]setDelegate:self];

    ArrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"MacLeodsAccessories.png", @"MacleodsBag.png", @"MacleodsBag1.png", @"MacleodsBag2.png", @"MacleodsCollar.png", @"MacleodsCushions.png",  @"MacleodsPurse.png", @"MacleodsTeaAndCoffee.png", nil];
}

//datasource and delegate method
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [ArrayOfImages count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell myImage]setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:[ArrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
```

This is probably coded all wrong and may very well be redundant but or might be exactly what I need, I just don't know how to correct it and what I'd put in here that would make this work.

```
    [[cell myImage]setGestureRecognizers:[ArrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}
```

If anyone could help out I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to a selection within a UICollectionView, you have to [implement at least one method in the UICollectionViewDelegate Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UICollectionViewDelegate) which your UICollectionViewController already conforms to.

Start with:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Place a breakpoint in this method, and you'll see that everytime you touch an element of your collection view, this method is fired and includes an indexPath for you.

A common approach for what you describe would then involve getting the image referenced by that path, placing it inside of a larger UIImageView and adding that view to the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create two or more UICollectionview. What you can do, when second page is going to visible reload Collectionview with empty array. And Once your page will visible load new set of images into Collectionview and vice-versa.